# Air chuck replacement

Tags: repair, replace, compressor, air

I have an air chuck similar to the one pictured.  The gasket in the chuck at the end of the short hose is missing so it won't seal around a tire valve and as a result, cant inflate the tire.

When I try to remove the chuck by turning the hex-nut-shaped point just below the chuck, the whole assembly just spins.  I can't tell if the chuck is threaded on or if its some kind of compression fitting.
[image]
If anyone has any experience with these and can guide me on how to replace the chuck, or maybe even where I could find replacement little gaskets, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks to you all in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The joint at the end you're working with is a compression fitting and you'll not be able to remove it there. You ***might*** be able to remove it at the body of the air chuck, but I'd bet it'll break the body. Realistically, the type which is shown is considered a "throw away", which means, once it's broke or not useable anymore, you should just look to replace it. I get it, as it is sort of a waste ... but that's what way of things these days.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: Before you chuck it you could try getting a pack of o-rings with varying sizes and see if you can get a fit. Googling air chuck o-rings brings up many options.

Comment: @GdD are you reading over my shoulder while I write up my answer ?

Comment: Great minds obviously think alike @Criggie

Answer (score 11):

Definitely a compression fitting - designed to be unserviceable.

Your first  option is boring - get an assortment of O rings and see if any of them fit the need.

[image]

---

You could get a barbed air chuck in the same style, or one that has more of a bicycle-style of latch, or even one that you just hold in place.

[image]  [image]

You would cut the compression fitting off cleanly leaving as much hose as possible.

Slip a suitably-sized jubilee clip / hose clamp over, then ram the barbs up the hosepipe.  It may help to soak the end of the hose in a cup of boiled hot water to soften it.  Don't use gas or flame.  A hot air blower may help but they tend to scorch.  Hot water is best.

Last, wrap the clamp in electrical tape or heatshrink so it can't catch on anything.

---

I've repaired bike pumps with these solutions.  While bike fixes may sound sub par for a car, remember a car tyre is 30-40 PSI, whereas a bike tyre is anything from 40-100 PSI.  If the fix works for a bike, it will work with a car.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you CAN cut the hose and fit another chuck with either a new compression fitting or some kind of clamp.

Cutting the compression fitting in order to save a centimeter of the hose is an option, too, but the connection will be less reliable.